# If K is a field, $X$ and $Y$ are sets such that $K[X]≃K[Y]$ then $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to see if there is proof for that.
Let $K$ be a commutative ring, $X=\{x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n} \}$  and $Y = \{y_{1}, y_{2}, ..., y_{m} \}$. Let $K[X] = K[x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}]$.
Then for every commutative $K$-algebra $Y$ with the $m$-tuple $(y_{1}, y_{2}, ..., y_{m})$ elements, there exist a unique algebra homomorphism from $K[X] = K[x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}]$ to $Y$, by the universal property of $K[X]$ (since it is a free algebraic structure), such that each $x_{i}$ maps to a corresponding $y_{j}$, which implies that $m\geq n$.

Similarly for $K[Y ] = K[y_{1}, y_{2}, ..., y_{m}]$, we have that for every commutative K-algebra X with the $n$-tuple $(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n})$ elements, there exist a unique algebra homomorphism from $K[Y ] = K[y_{1}, y_{2}, ..., y_{m}]$ to $X$,
by the universal property of $K[Y ]$, such that each $y_{j}$ maps to a corresponding $x_{i}$, which implies that $n\geq m$.

Since $m\geq n$ and $n\geq m$ implies that $n = m$. Hence, $|X|=|Y|$.

Does this make some sense? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably (by choice of notation) you intend the $x$'s and $y$'s to be algebraically independent over the base field $K$? Then you are asking about well-definedness of transcendence degree?

Comment: I don't find your argument convincing. For the first half, an algebra  homomorphism from $K[X[$ onto $K[Y]$ can't work by mapping members of $X$ to members of $Y$ if $|Y| > |X|$, but it could map $X$ to some other set of generators of $K[Y]$. What you have to prove is that no set of generators of $K[Y]$ can have fewer than $|Y|$ elements.

Comment: Yes, actually I wanted to use the same $K[X]$ and $K[Y]$ instead of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. If need be, it can be amended but should not run away from proving that if two polynomial rings, depending on X and Y, are isomorphic; then X and Y have the same order.